# How to clear screen or canvas on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, canvas

I need to implement an option in my application that will clear the screen. The application is basically to acheive free-hand drawing. Please help me on how to clear the drawing canvas. I need to have a button for that purpose.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the canvas depends on how you do the drawing. If you are drawing using vectors (like saving touch points and then drawing lines between them), then you can simply delete all the lines or points in your drawing and redraw the canvas. If you are drawing directly to some bitmap, you can clear the canvas simply by drawing a filled rectangle over the whole canvas. See also [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373181/undo-in-painting-apps-like-penultimate-and-idraft/4374096#4374096) regarding the drawing representation.